# Using DreamObjects to store assets

Tags: assets

Has anyone used Dreamhost's cloud service: DreamObjects, an Object-Based-Storage to host their assets? If so, how do you configure this with Craft 2.6.2911?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you're trying to add another [Assets Source Type](https://craftcms.com/classreference/assetsourcetypes/BaseAssetSourceType).

Unfortunately, this isn't possible in Craft 2. This feature is expected to be introduced in [Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/3).

> **Volume Types**
>
> Asset Sources have been renamed to “Volumes” in Craft 3, and their API has been dramatically simplified. In addition to Craft’s built-in Local, S3, Google, and Rackspace Volume types, plugins are now able to supply their own. There’s even a base Volume class that makes it really easy to implement Flysystem-based Volume types.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey, the $ question now is wether to start coding with 2.6 or wait and hopefully omitting any conversion work.

Comment: The Craft 3 beta is expected by the end of the year, with the official release planned for early next year. If it were me, I'd just build it out with 2.6, and use a different assets source.

Comment: Absolutely, I thought it might have been more imminent.